# ampps Not Found - 404 The requested URL was not found on this server solution

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, port, ampps

[ampps .404 The requested URL was not found on this server solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4htiE.png)

please i was using xampp for my local server , i upgraded to ampps today and all my code is not running in browser again ,and the ampps is running perfectly , what could be done to fix this please

Comment: It _seems_ that the `Apache` document root may have change? ... I'd check that first.